# Get the current selected value of MUI autocomplete multiselect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, multi-select, mui-autocomplete

I am using MUI autocomplete multi-select.
I am trying to get the one selected option by the user, but I can only achieve the list of multiple selected values. The selected value should be an object containing id and typeName, but it returns the array of selected objects, not the one that I just selected right now.

I tried slicing the array, and it works in selection but not when I deselect any option. On the other hand, I tried with semicolon-separated string but I can't see any help from that

Here is my autocomplete multi-select component;

```js
export default function MultiSelectCategoryDropdown({
  names,
  defaultValue,
  setFieldValue,
  label,
  setValues,
  values,
}) {
  const handleCategoryChange = (setFieldValue, value, values) => {
    const valueToSave = value.map((itm) => itm.typeName).join(";");
    console.log(valueToSave);
    const currentSelection = value.slice(-1).pop();
    console.log(currentSelection);
    setFieldValue("categories", value);
    // const indexToRemove = values.categoriesAttributes.findIndex((obj) => {
    //   return (
    //     obj.reimbursementType &&
    //     obj.reimbursementType.typename === value.typeName
    //   );
    // });
    // if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
    //   values.categoriesAttributes.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    // } else {
    //   values.categoriesAttributes.push({
    //     totalAllowedLimit: 0,
    //     allocationEndDate: "",
    //     reimbursementType: value,
    //   });
    // }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        sx={addInputStyles}
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={names}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.typeName}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          handleCategoryChange(setFieldValue, value, values);
        }}
        renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={option}
            value={option}
            sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
            {...props}
          >
            {option?.typeName}
            {selected ? <CheckIcon color="info" /> : null}
          </MenuItem>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label={label} />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```